# Creating surrounding polygons using QGIS?

Tags: donut-polygons

[image: For example: I created the small polygon (red), now I want to create the bigger polygon (green) surrounding the small (common boundary). How to do this?]

For example: I created the small polygon (red), now I want to create the bigger polygon (green) surrounding the small (common boundary).

How to do this using QGIS 2.18.4 ?

Comment: Do you already have a polygon that represents the red+green area?  If you are trying to digitize the outer boundary then what steps have you tried when editing so far?

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your question correctly you basically need to create a buffer around your red polygon, and then if you want a polygon of only that buffered area you need to erase the hole in the middle of the buffered area that is your original polygon.

In QGIS you use the `vector > spatial analysis > buffer` tool to create the buffer. You need to set the distance of the buffer to suit you (in the units of the projection you're working in). Then use the `vector > geoprocessing > difference` tool to find the difference between your buffered polygon and your original polygon. The output will be the buffered area only.

Comment: I want to create 2 polygons with different attribution. For example, the red polygon is "house" and the green polygon is "grass".

Comment: You then need to add an attribute field for each polygon and populate it with the correct values. You can do this easily for such a small example by opening the attribute table for each polygon and adding a new field.

Answer (score 1):

@scabecks describes a perfectly valid approach that will work.  However, here is a one-step alternative.  Using the Multiple-ring Buffer plugin, set the number of rings to 1.  It will then produce the doughnut without the need for the differencing step.